# Docker Created Volume Does Not Exist With Inspect

Tags: docker

I am new to volumes in Docker.

Following [Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), I created a volume called `mochawesome` with:

```
docker create -v /mochawesome-reports --name mochawesome dman777/vista-e2e-test-runner
```

I see it existing:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
273b14f7e0ea        dman777/vista-e2e-test-runner   "./run_test.sh"          3 minutes ago       Created                                 mochawesome
```

However if I do `docker volume inspect mochawesome` I get:

```
Error: No such volume: mochawesome
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `--name` in `docker create` specifies the name of the container (not the name of the volume). Therefore `docker volume inspect` cannot find this name.

To create a named volume use `docker create -v my-named-volume:/mochawesome-reports --name mochawesome dman777/vista-e2e-test-runner`. Then you can use `docker volume inspect my-named-volume`.

Comment: Doesn't the colon `:` represent a shared volume with a host in `my-named-volume:/mochawesome-reports`? in this case, I want  a shared volume between two docker containers and not the host.

Comment: docker create -v /mochawesome-reports --name mochawesome dman777/vista-e2e-test-runner  . Look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Comment: That is exactly what I used. Why isn't docker volume inspect finding it?

Comment: Use "docker inspect container" to find "Mount" "Name". Then "docker volume inspect mountNameId"

Comment: I did...both by name and by id. All of this is in my original post.

Comment: The only way to do this is `docker create -v my-named-volume:/mochawesome-reports`. I'm not sure what docker documentation is doing with their example in the original post as `docker create -v /mochawesome-reports --name mochawesome dman777/vista-e2e-test-runner ` does not create a data volume container.